# Consulta HQL em C#

Tags: c#, hql

Galera, estou tendo dificuldades com HQL e C#. Tenho o seguinte método:

```
public IList<int> GetListYear(Guid educationalInstitutionId, Guid academicLevelId, Guid? locationId, Guid? programOfferedId)
{
    //Implementar o HQL
}
```

E tenho a seguinte query:

```
"select distinct ConclusionYear
from AlumniProgramOffered
inner join AlumniSignup
inner join ProgramOffered*
inner join Program
where AlumniSignup.EducationalInstitution.Identity = educationalInstitutionId
and Program.AcademicLevel.Identity = academicLevelId
and ProgramOffered.Location.Identity = locationId or locationId is null
and ProgramOffered.Identity = programOfferedId or programOfferedId is null"
```

Preciso, através do HQL, realizar essa consulta passando os parâmetros que eu recebo no meu método **GetListYear**

Answer (score 0):

Para ter certeza de como esta consulta ficaria, precisaria do código de todas as suas entidades. Mas, provavelmente, sua consulta HQL ficaria parecida com isto:

```
select distinct ConclusionYear as cy
from AlumniProgramOffered as apo
 join apo.AlumniSignup as as
 join as.ProgramOffered as po
 join po.Location as loc
 join po.Program as pr
 join pr.AcademicLevel as al
 join pr.EducationalInstitution as edu
where edu.Identity = :educationalInstitutionId
 and al.Identity = :academicLevelId
 and loc.Identity = :locationId or locationId is null
 and po.Identity = :programOfferedId or programOfferedId is null
```

Isto, claro, é só a consulta HQL. O restante do código para a chamada deste HQL eu estou assumindo que você já saiba como fazer.